# How can I handle key{press|up|down} events with Sveltestrap components

Tags: svelte, sveltestrap

I am trying to add some custom on:keydown handling for a SvelteStrap  element; the naive approach would (seem) to be:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Card, CardBody } from 'sveltestrap';
  
  function handlekey(e) {
    // handler code goes here
  }
</script>

<Card on:keydown={handlekey}>
</Card>
```

In my actual code, I'm using tabindex to make the card focus-able, and I can successfully capture `on:click` events, but nothing seems to provoke a call to `handlekey()`

A simple REPL demonstrating the concept is [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/0f6228092aa4453799007262d0dfb561?version=3.55.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the SvelteStrap Card just doesn't listen on key events. You may wrap your Card into something that can listen on them :

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { Card, CardBody } from 'sveltestrap'; 
    
    function handleclick(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    
    function handlekey(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
</script>

<div tabindex=0 on:keydown={handlekey} on:keypress={handlekey} on:keyup={handlekey}>
    <Card on:click={handleclick}>
        <CardBody>Hello World</CardBody>
    </Card>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I sort of thought that might be the case, but I was hoping someone with more experience could point out a n00b error on my part ...